# Metodo para eliminar un objeto de un archivo binario

Tags: java, excepciones, serialización

estoy haciendo un ejercicio, en el cual puedo introducir, listar, buscar y eliminar uno o todos los objetos serializables que guardo en un archivo .dat. Me funcionan todos los metodos menos el de eliminar unos solo.

```
/**
     * Método para eliminar un mueble
     * ==============================
     * @param codigo 
     */
    public static void eliminarMueble(String codigo){
        // Declaramos un objeto mueble
        Muebles mueble;

        try (ObjectInputStream lectura = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("MUEBLES.DAT"));){

            // Declaramos el flujo de salida de datos y lo conectamos
            File archivoTemporal = new File("ARCHIVOTEMP.DAT");
            ObjectOutputStream escritura;

            // Evaluo el codigo para ver si esta o no y luego lo grabo con o sin cabecera
            while (true) {                
                mueble = (Muebles) lectura.readObject();
                if (String.valueOf(mueble.getCodigo()).equals(codigo)) {
                    if (archivoTemporal.exists()) {
                        escritura = new MiObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivoTemporal, true));
                    } else {
                        escritura = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivoTemporal));
                    }
                }
            } // Fin del while
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe el fichero");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error de E/S:" + ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se puede encontrar la clase" + ex);
        }

    } // Fin del metodo eliminarMueble
```

Este método lo lanzo desde aqui:

```
// Boton eliminar un mueble
    private void btnEliminarMuebleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        // Declarmos una instancia de Mueble
        Muebles m;
        if (txtCodigo.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El código esta vacio, por favor rellenelo para eliminar un mueble");
        } else {
            if (OperacionesFicheros.existeRegistro(txtCodigo.getText())) {
                m = OperacionesFicheros.buscaRegistro(txtCodigo.getText());
                int respuesta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Deseas eliminar todos los muebles?");
                if (respuesta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    OperacionesFicheros.eliminarMueble(txtCodigo.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has eliminado todos todos los muebles");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código no existe");
            }
        }
        limpiarTabla();
        mostrarTabla();
        txtCodigo.requestFocus();
    }
```

Esta es la excepción que salta:

```
mar 31, 2019 5:04:07 PM controlador.OperacionesFicheros eliminarMueble
GRAVE: null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2960)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1540)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at controlador.OperacionesFicheros.eliminarMueble(OperacionesFicheros.java:141)
    at vista.AppGestionMueblesQuesadaRomeroLuis.btnEliminarMuebleActionPerformed(AppGestionMueblesQuesadaRomeroLuis.java:414)
    at vista.AppGestionMueblesQuesadaRomeroLuis.access$1000(AppGestionMueblesQuesadaRomeroLuis.java:22)
    at vista.AppGestionMueblesQuesadaRomeroLuis$11.actionPerformed(AppGestionMueblesQuesadaRomeroLuis.java:173)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.focusLost(BasicButtonListener.java:198)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.focusLost(AWTEventMulticaster.java:229)
    at java.awt.Component.processFocusEvent(Component.java:6431)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6295)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1024)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:690)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.dispatchAndCatchException(KeyboardFocusManager.java:2601)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.processCurrentLightweightRequests(KeyboardFocusManager.java:2693)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager$4.run(KeyboardFocusManager.java:2804)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Sería interesante saber dónde salta la excepción y de qué tipo es. ¿Es en el bucle `while`?

Comment: No se muy mirar muy bien eso aun, me salta justo la de E/S

Comment: Añade a la pregunta la salida en consola que te aparece al hacer clic en `btnEliminar`. El texto de la excepción.

Comment: ¿para qué es el archivo temporal?

Comment: Es parte del ejercicio de la asignatura del grado superior de DAW, me funiona todo menos eliminar, es para ir leyendo el archivo donde almaceno los objetos y cuando llega el objeto con el codigo para borrar no lo grabo en el archivo, y luego renombro el archivo temporal, es lo que nos pide el ejercicio

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema reside en tu evaluación de código a través del bucle `while`.

Un bucle `while` se ejecutará mientras la expresión condicional se cumpla, es decir, sea `True`. Como el resultado de `while (true)` siempre es `True`, el loop será infinito, a no ser que haya alguna instrucción del tipo `break` que rompa el bucle.

La funcionalidad interna de ese bucle `while` es leer los `bytes` de un fichero y realizar acciones en base lo leído. Cuando termina de leer todo el contenido, el bucle sigue funcionando pero no tiene de dónde más leer así que salta una excepción [`EOFException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) que indica un problema al alcanzar el final del fichero (en tu caso, intentar leer de un sitio de donde ya no hay nada más que leer).

Si entras a la API de Java y revisas la clase [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), verás que existe un método [`available`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available--), mediante el cual puedes comprobar si hay más `bytes` disponibles para leer.

Mediante el bucle siguiente:

```
while (lectura.available() > 0) {
    // Realiza acciones necesarias
}
```

Realizarás una lectura del fichero abierto con `ObjectInputStream` mientras el número de `bytes` sea mayor de `0`.

Puedes capturar las excepciones a través de la clase [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html).